# Print prints into the Messages notebook rather than into the evaluation notebook

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, output

Some time ago I noticed that the results of the evaluating the function `Print[something]` does not emerge in a new cell created in the notebook where the operation was evaluated. Instead it appears in the Messages notebook. Evidently some global option has been involuntarily switched. Do you know, which one? What should I do to return the behavior of `Print` back to normal?

Comment: Well, `$Output` was probably changed.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that is also my expectation. How to change it back?

Comment: Try Edit/Preferences/Messages and reset to defaults or just set what you need to set.

Comment: What does `InputForm[$Output]` say?

Comment: @Szabolcs It says {OutputStream["stdout", 1]}

Comment: So have you checked Preferences/Messages?

Comment: @Kuba That's it! I did not see that it specifies where to send the Print output. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record:

You can do this via `Edit/Preferences/Messages`:

[image]